# how to store hidden value in mysql

Tags: database, save, hidden-field

[image]

Hi Everyone;

I would like to save hidden values in database table stressselfssessment. In that table I have created three column stressassessment_id (PK) , choice, question_id (FK). Everytime i tried to store value in stressassessment table in choice row only last value saved in table.
I tried the below code but it does not work fine.

```
<?php

    //Set question number
    $n=1;
    $number = $_GET['n'];
    //Get total number of questions
    $query = "select * from questions where questions_id=$number";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $total=    mysql_num_rows($results);

//Check if form was submitted
if($_POST){

$number = $_POST['number'];
$choice = $_POST['choice'];
$next=$number+1;
//Get total number of questions

$query   = "SELECT * FROM questions ";
$results = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$total   =  mysql_num_rows($results);
//Get correct choice

$query="insert into stressselfassessment (choice,questions_id) 
     values('$choice' , '$number' )";
$insert_row= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

   //VALIDATE INSERT

//compare answer with result

if($number == $total){
header("Location: final.php");
exit();
} else {
 header("Location: question.php?n=".$next);
}

} 

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stress Assessment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Stress Assessment</h1>
    </div>
      </header>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="current">Question <?php echo $number; ?> </div>

<form method="post" >
  <ul >
<?php 

 $sqlquestions = "select question,questions_id, choice1, choice2,choice3, choice4 from questions where questions_id=$number";

$resques = mysql_query($sqlquestions) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resques))
{  
echo $row['question'];

?>

<li><input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['choice1']; ?>"  /><?php echo $row['choice1']; ?><br>
<input type="hidden" name="choice7" value="1" > 
<input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['choice2']; ?>"  /><?php echo $row['choice2']; ?><br>
<input type="hidden" name="choice7" value="2" > 
<input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['choice3']; ?>"  /><?php echo $row['choice3']; ?><br>
<input type="hidden" name="choice7" value="3" > 
<input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['choice4']; ?>"  /><?php echo $row['choice4']; ?><br>  
<input type="hidden" name="choice7" value="4" > 
</li>
<?php 

}

?>
</ul>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Please Select" />
 <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which hidden value you are trying to find?

Comment: I want to store hidden value 1,2,3 and 4. When user select any one radio box the hidden value on below stored in database. For example, if user select choice1 radio button on clicking next button the value of 1 insert into database likewise, if user select choice2 radio button on clicking next button the value of 2 saved into database.

Comment: thank you guys for your time. I got the answer.